# scoffing his granola

Tags: british-english

In this Passage what is the meaning of "scoffing his granola" sentence:
He’s a terrible time keeper. We go on and on at
the kids about time keeping but the Head’s late for everything. The assembly
hall is full and he’s still scoffing his granola.

Comment: Have you found out what Granola is and when it is eaten?  Have you looked up the verb “scoff?

Answer (score 1):

"Scoffing" means "eating" and implies a greedy, rushed action. Granola is a breakfast cereal mix. The Head is late for the first assembly because he's still greedily stuffing cereal into his mouth. If we presume that "we" are the teachers who follow the Head's strict timekeeping orders then the use of "scoffing" takes on a perjorative slight.

Comment: In the US "scoffing down" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: And I'll note that "scarf down" is probably more common.

Comment: @HotLicks My gut instinct says _scarf_ is more common than _scoff_ as well, which is interesting considering that _scarf_ is just a variant of _scoff_ that arose as late as the mid-20th century.

Comment: I prefer my folk etymology, which associates the verb with the cormorant.  :)

Comment: The question is flagged 'British English', and 'scarf' in this sense appears to be US.

Answer (score 0):

Even with his breakfast (**scoffing** his granola) he is late and in a hurry!

**scoff**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/scoff)

> To eat (food) quickly.